# Multi-Instance MSI with InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le, installshield-2012

I've created a .msi of my product using InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition project via Visual Studio 2012. It works fine when installing a single instance of it. But when trying to install another, the maintenance view pops up and asks me if I want to repair, modify or remove my product.

What I want is to be able to run the same .MSI multiple times installing multiple instances of the very same product. If I want to repair, modify or remove it I would want to do it via the Control Panel - Programs.

I have found an article covering what I want http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/RunningASetupMultipleTimes.htm but I can't seem to find "Maintenance Experience" under the "General Information view.". So my question is - is this feature not supported in InstallShield 2012 LE? If it isn't is there another way of achieving what I want in InstallShield 2012 LE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you found applies to InstallScript projects, which are only available in the Professional and Premier editions of InstallShield. Multiple-instance support for MSI-based projects (such as what the limited edition builds) is a very different endeavor, requiring the pre-creation of [instance transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369528.aspx). It is also only supported in the Professional and Premier editions; the limited edition has no support for transforms, much less automatically creating instance transforms.

As for whether you can do what you want, I would more information on your underlying use case to answer that. Why is it you want to be able to install the product multiple times on the same machine? I cannot really recommend MSI-based multiple instance installations; they are very hard to create and service correctly.